Type of collision of two billiard balls
My textbook has the following question:

If the potential energy of two billiard balls depends only on the seperation distance between their centres, is the collison elastic or inelastic? (Note: we are talking here of potential energy corresponding to the force during collision, not gravitational potential energy)

This only signifies that the total mechanical energy is conserved, doesn't it? It doesn't explicitly say that kinetic energy would be conserved after the collision, but my textbook says that this indeed is an elastic collision. Why? I'm so confused.

What is the name of your textbook?

@BobD Physics Part I: Textbook for Class XI by NCERT. An Indian textbook for high school students. You can check out the PDF for free—it's a Google search away.

Does the book cover Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics?

As I've already said, it's a high school textbook. So, it doesn't cover those.

Ok. See the latest update to my answer.

I think what the authors are trying to get at is that if the total energy in a system is kinetic energy plus a relative position dependent potential energy, then the total energy is conserved, i.e. all interactions are elastic.
I would agree that they have not stated the question well as a system could have such a position dependent potential energy plus a frictional interaction that leads to the transformation of kinetic energy into internal energy.
I think they imagined that their "only" precludes that additional term, but I would suggest they would want some more like:

If the only interaction between two billiard balls is a potential energy
that depends only on the seperation distance between their centres,
is the collison elastic or inelastic?

to make the question valid.

I'm not sure we need the additional "only". A frictional interaction would allow for the balls to occupy the same positions with different potential energies, making their potential energy not dependent only on their separation. The PE is defined to depend only on the position state of the balls, it can't depend on how they got there, as non-conservative frictional forces do.

@Malcolm But the conservation of mechanical energy doesn't imply that the collision will be elastic; it's the conservation of kinetic energy only that implies so, doesn't it? Or am I getting this wrong?

@archthegreat, In an elastic system it is the total of kinetic and potential energy that stays constant.  During collisions kinetic energy can be converted to potential energy and back.

@NuclearHoagie, it is quite possible for the Potential Energy to be entirely position dependent even if there is also a non-conservative force at work.  When the balls are back to the same original position the Potential Energy is the same as it was before.  It is the Kinetic Energy that will be less by the amount lost to the non-conservative force.

Imagine two rubber "super-balls" colliding. When they collide they compress and the distance between their centres is proportional to the stored potential energy which is converted back to the kinetic energy of the ball as they separate after the collision. The kinetic energy is the same before and after the collision.
If the balls were made of something like putty, they would undergo permanent plastic deformation during the collision and the distance between centres during the collision would not be proportional to the potential energy of the balls, as some of the kinetic energy is lost in the plastic deformation process and the creation of heat. This would be classified as an inelastic collision.
However, it is not as clear cut as you might imagine. Consider the case where the superballs are coated in a super-superglue that sets immediately during the collision, then the balls would not be able to separate after the collision and kinetic energy would not be conserved. In the absence of super-superglue we can imagine harpoon like spikes on the each ball that penetrate the surface of the other ball and prevent the balls separating after the collision so technically this would be an inelastic collision even though potential energy is stored during the collision, the system prevents the potential energy being converted back to kinetic energy. However this is a somewhat contrived artificial set up and probably not intended to be part of the question.

(+1) Potential energy as defined between 2 balls (as opposed to potential energy of a single ball) seems rather odd... If the potential energy between A and B is 10, and the potential energy between A and C is 20, then what is the potential energy of A by itself? Intuitively the notion of potential energy seems to be something intrinsic to one object, instead of some relative quantity between 2 objects?

Potential energy (in this case elastic potential energy) is defined as the energy of position and kinetic energy is defined as the energy of motion.
I don’t see why these definitions would depend upon whether or not a collision is elastic. In other words, while mechanical energy is not conserved in an inelastic collision, I don’t see why an inelastic collision would change the definition of elastic potential energy, as your book seems to suggest.
Let the two billiard balls be suspended by strings and collide like two pendulums. If the collision is perfectly elastic, at maximum compression the separation between centers will correspond to an elastic potential energy equal to the gravitational potential energy of the balls prior to release.
On the other hand, if the collision is inelastic, the separation between centers will be greater than that for the elastic collision, and thus the elastic potential energy less, due to internal friction losses during compression.
Although the separation between centers for the elastic and inelastic collision are different, the elastic potential energy is still defined in terms of the separation between centers.
Hope this helps.

The question is actually trying to get the students to reason that if $V(\vec r)=V(r)$, then in $\mathcal H=T(p)+V(r)$ you have a conserved quantity, because there is no way for the energy to be converted into other forms. That is also why the standard Rutherford scattering is considered elastic.

@naturallyInconsistent Interesting. I’ve asked for info on the book.

I believe the answer is that the collision is elastic. Here the potential is purely a function of position and hence the system is conservative. If there is no loss of energy, then the collision must be elastic.
